# ext[key].bind is not a function when I do npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

Was having an issue with the dependencies when i did npm i so i ran

npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps @material-ui/core

in the terminal. Now when I do npm start I get this:

```sh
 mern-stack-client@0.1.0 start

 react-scripts start

C:\Users\t\Prideshow\Prideshow\client\node_modules\renderkid\node_modules\domutils\index.js:12
                DomUtils[key] = ext[key].bind(DomUtils);
                                         ^

TypeError: ext[key].bind is not a function
    at C:\Users\t\Prideshow\Prideshow\client\node_modules\renderkid\node_modules\domutils\index.js:12:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\t\Prideshow\Prideshow\client\node_modules\renderkid\node_modules\domutils\index.js:11:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\t\Prideshow\Prideshow\client\node_modules\renderkid\node_modules\domutils\index.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\t\Prideshow\prideshow\client
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-scripts start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\t\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-12T16_22_08_251Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?